# use nextage hand camera in simulation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to use the KaWaDa nextage's hand cameras in simulation? I.e. can I get images from a simulator, e.g. moveit/rviz or gazebo? If so, how? Is someone aware of a tutorial they could point me to?

If I just run `roslaunch nextage_ros_bridge hands_ueye.launch`, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1482331372.271498218, 1478.945000009]: Failed to load nodelet [/right_hand_ueye_nodelet] of  type [ueye_cam/ueye_cam_nodelet] even after refreshing the cache: Failed to load library /opt/ros/indigo/lib//libueye_cam_nodelet.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = libueye_api.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

Is this supposed to work with simulations or would it only work with real cameras?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250547/use-nextage-hand-camera-in-simulation/) by [robotfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28731/robotfan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2016-12-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The launch file you referred to is, as in @gvdhoorn's answer, uses the camera driver that accesses the real hardware.

> Is this supposed to work with simulations or would it only work with real cameras?

Simulation of NEXTAGE Open (whether RViz or Gazebo) isn't equipped with camera imitated yet. I'd like to see this feature realized too. Could you open an enhancement request at https://github.com/tork-a/rtmros_nextage/issues for NEXTAGE?

UPDATE 20161222: [Ticketed](https://github.com/tork-a/rtmros_nextage/issues/278).

UPDATE 20170523: [Cameras on Gazebo added](https://github.com/tork-a/rtmros_nextage/pull/330)

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message basically tells you that the `ueye_cam_nodelet` can't load one of its dependencies (ie: `libueye_api.so`). This would fail, irrespective of whether you are using a simulated robot or not. You just don't have the uEye drivers installed.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1